# Serialize Json object with "multi-type" property

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm following the [Create a web API with ASP.NET Core and MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-mongodb) Tutorial

And I'm missing something very basic, how to serialize a Json object that has a property that could be "multi-type". That is, this property could be a string, or another object.

This is the original Json sample in the tutorial:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5bfd996f7b8e48dc15ff215d"),
  "Name" : "Design Patterns",
  "Author" : "Ralph Johnson"
}
```

This is the original POCO Model in the tutorial:

```
public class Book
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

When I call the "Post" and "Get" action on the WebApi Controller, the original Json model is serialized correctly into an instance of Book, saved into the database and retrieved correctly from the web service as expected.

But, I need to add a "MultiUse" property, where `MultiUse` could either be a string or an object, or something else, for example:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5bfd996f7b8e48dc15ff215d"),
 "Name" : "Design Patterns",
 "Author" : "Ralph Johnson",
 "MultiUse": "Some String"
}
```

or

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5bfd996f7b8e48dc15ff215d"),
 "Name" : "Design Patterns",
 "Author" : "Ralph Johnson",
 "MultiUse": {
     "foo":"bar"
  }
}
```

If I try to Post an object, this `MultiUse` property is serialized as another .Net type.

[image]

What type should `MultiUse` be in the POCO Model? I've tried `Object`, `Dynamic`, `BsonDocument`, but it is clear I think that AspNet and MongoDb driver will not automatically serialize it as I need it.

This multi-value property is pretty much the only reason I want to use MongoDB, I just want to save whatever is in that property into the database.

This situation works without problems in ExpressJS, but I need .Net because of client requirements.

Of course, I can just drop the strongly typed schema and use the MongoDB net driver functions to insert, update and query without the models. But since this "should" be a common scenario I just wanted to know how is this being handled.

Comment: Would the use of generics solve your problem?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554853/making-json-net-mongodb-bson-play-nice-together/59556012#59556012 ?

Comment: If the types are well known, you can follow the guidelines for polymorphism here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/

Comment: @user1344783 Thank you, type of MultiUse is unknown

Comment: Then use JObect for newtonsoft or JElement for System.Text.Json

Comment: @user1344783 JElement didn't work, mongo saves an empty object,

Comment: @user1344783 with JObject  it throws: The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Comment: @user1344783 The dynamic serializer works if the value is a Json object, but it breaks if it's a string, I suppose you have to write the logic to "determine" what the value is and be able to create a BSonDocument

Comment: I'll use [yessql](https://github.com/sebastienros/yessql) instead, the value is serialized correctly and I can use MSSql to save documents (json), so far very good (almost magical)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this problem,
my suggestion is to import [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), then use `MultiUse` as `JObject`, or if `MultiUse` is array as `Jarray`.

Comment: Make sure to use the Core Version if using core.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

Comment: JObject throws   `The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

Comment: @TheOne try using `JToken` not `JObject`

Comment: @GuruStron The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken